# How to get the type/interface of an unknown imported function in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, node-modules

I've heard that it is bad practice to set an expected type of a variable to `any`.

However, I don't understand, how I can get a return type of an imported function, which returns an object, which is only used in the library.

As an example, if I would like to use the `crypto.createCipheriv()` function provided by Node.js, which returns a *`Cipher` object* as [stated in the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatecipherivalgorithm-key-iv-options), I would not known how to give a variable this type.

Answer (score 1):

```
const variable: ReturnType<crypto.createCipheriv>;
```